# How to turn a csv table in R or Python into a sentence by sentence output csv

Tags: python, r, csv, format

I already obtained a CSV binary file as the following sample:

```
Apple    Orange    Tea    Coffee    Cookie    Group
  1        0        1        0         1        A
  0        1        1        0         1        B
  1        0        1        0         0        A
  1        1        1        0         0        A
  0        1        1        0         1        B
```

And I'd like to turn this table into a sentence format like (sentence by sentence, only record the item that binary appears to be 1):

```
Apple Tea Cookie A
Orange Tea Cookie B
Apple Tea A
Apple Orange Tea A
Orange Tea Cookie B
```

Comment: IN `R`, try `cat(paste(apply(df1[-ncol(df1)], 1, function(x) paste(names(x)[x==1], collapse=' ')), df1[[ncol(df1)]]), sep="\n")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would go along these lines in Python (assuming the file is tab-separated):

```
import csv

with open('file_name.csv', 'r') as flh:
    csvr = csv.reader(flh, delimiter='\t')

    result = []
    first = None
    for row in csvr:
        if first is None:
            first = row
        else:
            sent = []
            for i, el in enumerate(row[:-1]):
                if el.strip() == '1':
                    sent.append(first[i])
            sent.append(row[-1].strip())
            result.append(' '.join(sent))

    print (result)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pandas` module as follows:

```
df

   Apple    Orange  Group
0   1       1       A
1   0       1       A
2   0       1       B
3   0       0       A
4   1       0       B
5   1       0       A

strings = []
for i,j in df.iterrows():
    string = ''
    for k in j.keys():
        if j[k] == 1:
            string += k + ' '
        elif k == 'Group':
            string += j[k]
    strings.append(string)
```

Output:

```
print(strings)

['Apple Orange A', 'Orange A', 'Orange B', 'A', 'Apple B', 'Apple A']
```

Answer (score 1):

using csv and DictReader in python:

```
import csv
with open('your_file') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
        toprint = [key for key in row.keys() if row[key] == 1]
        toprint.append(row['Group'])
        print(toprint)
```

**outout:**

```
['apple', 'Tea', 'Cookie', 'A']
['Tea', 'Cookie', 'Orange', 'B']
['apple', 'Tea', 'A']
['apple', 'Tea', 'Orange', 'A']
['Tea', 'Cookie', 'Orange', 'B']
```